# Metasploit to connect to a target behind NAT

Tags: network, penetration-test, metasploit, meterpreter, nat

During a pentest and I experienced a weird problem with connecting to the target machine which is behind a NAT network the scenario is basically,

they have a public ip : 1.1.1.1

and there are multiple machines within the network with IPs 172.16.2.0/24

those machines can connect to each other but cannot reach the internet basically, and through the webshell you cannot ping anything because it takes the ip of the private machine which is unreachable from the internet

So is there any way I can either use bind or reverse shell?

Comment: This might help: https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-08/Miller/BH_US_08_Ty_Miller_Reverse_DNS_Tunneling_Shellcode.pdf

Comment: @Security Geek You mean the private IP's can't reach to Internet? You mean they are on  air gapped  gnetwork?

Comment: Yup they can't , also they use linux os not windows

Comment: @Security Geek You need atleast one machine  in that network  to be able to reach Internet. Then you  can use `netcat pivoting`. You can google that.

Comment: there is no way to get a reverse w/o doing so ? there are a couple of machines in the network but it's kinda of difficult to interact with it within only a webshell

Comment: @SecurityGeek Yeah... there is no way except pivoting.

Comment: In theory there are some more possibilities, but all of them require more privileges than pivoting, so in reality I agree to the above: your way to go is ncat or netcat pivoting/chaining.